# Telegram bot shop how to link to a product in a message

Tags: url, hyperlink, telegram-bot, inline

I am writing a telegram bot.  An inline message with a list of products is sent to the user.  Hunting so that under each position there is a link to the product.
I want product links to look and work like the example in the telegram documentation.
[image]

As I understand it, the only way to send a link to a product is to use the telegram api.  However, when I call it in code, a confirmation window appears.  I need the links to work without the confirmation box.  Tell me, please, how best to do this?